# How to mock metwork requests in calabash tests

Tags: android, mocking, calabash

I've written UI tests on calabash that interact with my backend. I need to mock network requests and give pre-configured json to my app instead of real response to server. How to implement in in Calabash? Should I switch my UI testing library to mockito or espresso?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using some service or framework to mock the backend.
Either mocking the service or the data object.

- [MockServer](http://www.mock-server.com/)
- [Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl)